# Apache Tomcat Load balancer Not load balancing the way I want

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing

I have an issue with my Apache Tomcat not load balancing the way I would like / if at all.

I have 1 Apache instance and 3 Tomcat instances.
I would like for the user when going to mysite.com be forward to one of the Tomcat nodes.
All the tomcat node are hosting the exact same application.
I would like Apache to go between the Tomcat instances via round robin. I.E. goes to Tomcat node 1 the next person is sent to Tomcat node 2 then node 3 ect.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

`worker.properties file:`

`worker.list=loadbalancerview`
`worker.loadbalancerview.method=Busyness`
`worker.loadbalancerview.type=lb`
`worker.loadbalancerview.balance_workers=COMPUTER1_usmview,COMPUTER2_usmview`
`worker.loadbalancerview.sticky_session=1`
`worker.COMPUTER1_usmview.port=8009`
`worker.COMPUTER1_usmview.host=COMPUTER1`
`worker.COMPUTER1_usmview.type=ajp13`
`worker.COMPUTER1_usmview.lbfactor=10`
`worker.COMPUTER2_usmview.port=8009`
`worker.COMPUTER2_usmview.host=COMPUTER2`
`worker.COMPUTER2_usmview.type=ajp13`
`worker.COMPUTER2_usmview.lbfactor=10`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all lines that state "lbfactor"
This tells Apache that you are doing a weighted load balance.
Only use lbfactor for a weighted load balancing.